# How to access array string outside of loop? C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm trying to sum the monthly sales total of my product (`Limonade`). I'm having trouble with my code outside the loop. All 12 of my array strings have the same value, that of the last array string (`monthLimonade[11]`).

My database query accurately sums the monthly sales as (`monthlyLimonade`). I verified that my array works inside the loop.

Where am I going wrong?

```
String[] monthLimonade = new String[12];

try
{
//CONNECTION STRING INFO...
cnn.Open();
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{

    Label lblmonthLimonade = new Label();

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        monthLimonade[i] = reader.GetString("monthlyLimonade");
        lblmonthLimonade.Text = monthLimonade[i];
    }
        //This label inside the reader loop gives correct output
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblmonthLimonade);
}
cnn.Close();
}
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "MySql, no connection!");
}

    int m1l = Int32.Parse(monthLimonade[0]);
    int m2l = Int32.Parse(monthLimonade[1]);
    int m3l = Int32.Parse(monthLimonade[2]);
    int m4l = Int32.Parse(monthLimonade[3]);
    int m5l = Int32.Parse(monthLimonade[4]);
    int m6l = Int32.Parse(monthLimonade[5]);
    int m7l = Int32.Parse(monthLimonade[6]);
    int m8l = Int32.Parse(monthLimonade[7]);
    int m9l = Int32.Parse(monthLimonade[8]);
    int m10l = Int32.Parse(monthLimonade[9]);
    int m11l = Int32.Parse(monthLimonade[10]);
    int m12l = Int32.Parse(monthLimonade[11]);

    // Here in my chart I get all the same values for every month "10516"

    this.chart1.Series["Limonade"].Points.AddXY("January", m1l);
    this.chart1.Series["Limonade"].Points.AddXY("February", m2l);
    this.chart1.Series["Limonade"].Points.AddXY("March", m3l);
    this.chart1.Series["Limonade"].Points.AddXY("April", m4l);
    this.chart1.Series["Limonade"].Points.AddXY("May", m5l);
    this.chart1.Series["Limonade"].Points.AddXY("June", m6l);
    this.chart1.Series["Limonade"].Points.AddXY("July", m7l);
    this.chart1.Series["Limonade"].Points.AddXY("August", m8l);
    this.chart1.Series["Limonade"].Points.AddXY("September", m9l);
    this.chart1.Series["Limonade"].Points.AddXY("October", m10l);
    this.chart1.Series["Limonade"].Points.AddXY("November", m11l);
    this.chart1.Series["Limonade"].Points.AddXY("December", m12l);
    flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(chart1);
```

Comment: What is the value of each string in your array?

Comment: Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem, there's no way to answer this. If each array element has the same value, then obviously the call to `reader.GetString("monthlyLimonade")` is always returning the same value. But you didn't show how that method works or what it does.

Comment: @ben Inside the loop (if I output to a label) I get output values of `monthLimonade[0]` = 2294.4, `monthLimonade[1]` = 3212.16, `monthLimonade[2]` = 4550.56, `monthLimonade[3]` = 5124, `monthLimonade[4]` = 7581, `monthLimonade[5]` = 6883, `monthLimonade[6]` = 10516, `monthLimonade[7]` = 6692, `monthLimonade[8]` = 8604, `monthLimonade[9]` = 10516, monthLimonade[10] = 0, monthLimonade[11] = 0. But when I use the intergers in my chart outside the loop they all have the same value as `monthLimonade[9]` = 10516.

Comment: @DaleWahl Obviously all element of array and all integer varuables will contain the same value `reader.GetString("monthlyLimonade")` that is the value of `monthlyLimonade` column of first record of result set.

Comment: Too many details are missing on this question - however I guess you need to refer: while (sqlReader.Read())...

Comment: @DaleWahl Let me know if the answer was helpful :)

Comment: @Reza Aghaei There was nothing wrong with my array. I found the problem was in my SQL statement, it was returning all 12 at once and I needed them returned one at a time. I fixed my SQL statement and everything worked out well. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @DaleWahl Happy to hear that you solved the problem yourself and thank you for your feedback. I hadn't seen your edit and I posted the answer based on your original question. But I checked your edit and I see that the problem is still there and to be useful for future readers I edited the answer and described the problem more clearly. Hope you find it helpful. I think kindly accepting the answer will make it more useful to future readers to avoid such misunderstanding of using an array in a loop :)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

The original answer is based on original question and is OK and can be used to solve the problem of edited question too, but the problem with edited question still is there and I try to describe it more clearly:

In line 01 the `reader.Read()` reads each row of result set and in loop statement in line 06 you set each element of array to the same value that is vauue of `monthlyLimonade` column of current row, so this will repeat for next row because of `reader.Read()` and at last, all element of your array will contain the value of `monthlyLimonade` of the last row in result set.

```
01: while (reader.Read())
02: {
03:     Label lblmonthLimonade = new Label();
04:     for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
05:     {
06:         monthLimonade[i] = reader.GetString("monthlyLimonade");
07:         lblmonthLimonade.Text = monthLimonade[i];
08:     }
09:     //This label inside the reader loop gives correct output
10:     flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lblmonthLimonade);
11: }
```

**Original Answer**

Obviously all element of array will contain the same value `reader.GetString("monthlyLimonade")` that is the value of `monthlyLimonade` column of first record of result set.

I think you need:

```
for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
{
    reader.Read();
    monthLimonade[i] = reader.GetString("monthlyLimonade");
}
```

But why you want to use such array and variables? As a better option I recommend using a `DataTable` instead:

```
var dataTable = new DataTable();
var connection = @"your connection string";
var command = "your command";
var dataAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(command, connection);

//Get data
dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
```

Then you can use `Rows` collection of that `DataTable`.

Comment: Why are you incrementing `i` twice?

Comment: I changed that from my while loop and I forget to remove it :) thanks for comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
monthLimonade[i] = reader.GetString("monthlyLimonade");
```

you inserting same value to array. thats the problem why u have same value.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are getting the right results inside the loop maybe you can try parsing and summing from within the loop it's self?

```
String[] monthLimonade = new String[12];
int mlSum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
         monthLimonade[i] = reader.GetString("monthlyLimonade");
         mlSum += Int32.Parse(monthLimonade[i]);
    }
```

So in each iteration of the loop you'll get this:

```
monthLimonade[0] = 2294.4
monthLimonade[1] = 3212.16
monthLimonade[2] = 4550.56
monthLimonade[3] = 5124
monthLimonade[4] = 7581
monthLimonade[5] = 6883
monthLimonade[6] = 10516
monthLimonade[7] = 6692
monthLimonade[8] = 8604
monthLimonade[9] = 10516
monthLimonade[10] = 0
monthLimonade[11] = 0
```

Which should sum to this:

```
mlSum = 65973.12
```

This should also allow you to debugg a little deeper by putting a breakpoints into the loop and seeing if Int.Parse is parsing your `reader.GetString("monthlyLimonade")` result each time.